# Column comparisons Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a collection of items that have a width and a height

```
A         B           C
Item    Width    Height
I1        1           1
I2        1           1
I3        1.25      1
I4        1           1.25
```

And I want to determine how many of each dimension we have

```
                    Width
            1       1.25        1.5 ...
            1       X           Y
            1.25    Z
Height      1.5
            ...

X = 2
Y = 1
Z = 1
```

I need to know what functions to look for to put into cell X, Y, and Z etc...

Looking for something like

```
X = Count row 2:5 where B(row) = 1 and C(row) = 1
Y = Count row 2:5 where B(row) = 1.25 and C(row) = 1
Z = Count row 2:5 where B(row) = 1 and C(row) = 1.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, but try this:

for x:

```
=countifs (B2:B ,"=1",C2:C ,"=1")
```

for y:

```
=countifs (B2:B ,"=1",C2:C ,"=1.25")
```

for z:

```
=countifs (B2:B ,"=1.25",C2:C ,"=1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have numerous possible combinations, consider making something like this...

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/a/imarketingguy.com/spreadsheets/d/1xepZr8ZCAS4-TV5jEM0imo2zFWqP7_YoptWCfRB4j_I/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Dimensions Count]

Get the unique values from the lengths and widths like this...

**Width**

```
=INDEX(UNIQUE(B2:B))
```

**Height**

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(C2:C))
```

**Grid**

Formula for first lookup (1:1)

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B,$E4,$C$2:$C,F$3)
```